# unable to login buildroot

Tags: linux-kernel, buildroot

i use buildroot and compile linux kenrenl and when i run QEMU,i cann't login to builroot, because i cann't see message "Welcome to buildroot" for login,

```
ata2.01: NODEV after polling detection
ata2.00: ATAPI: QEMU DVD-ROM, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
ata1.01: NODEV after polling detection
ata1.00: ATA-7: QEMU HARDDISK, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
ata1.00: 11502 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 
ata1.00: configured for MWDMA2
ata2.00: configured for MWDMA2
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      QEMU HARDDISK    2.5+ PQ: 0 
ANSI: 5
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 11502 512-byte logical blocks: (5.89 MB/5.62 MiB)
scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            QEMU     QEMU DVD-ROM     2.5+ PQ: 0 
ANSI: 5
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't 
support DPO or FUA
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as 
/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3
EXT4-fs (sda): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
EXT4-fs (sda): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
EXT4-fs (sda): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) readonly on device 8:0.
devtmpfs: mounted
Freeing unused kernel memory: 832K (ffffffff8186e000 - 
ffffffff8193e000)
Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 8192k
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1212K (ffff8800014d1000 - 
ffff880001600000)
Freeing unused kernel memory: 536K (ffff88000177a000 - 
ffff880001800000)
random: fast init done
EXT4-fs (sda): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is 
recommended
EXT4-fs (sda): re-mounted. Opts: 
block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,errors=remount-ro
Starting logging: OK
Initializing random number generator... done.
Starting network: OK

### here, i was unable to see message command for login,
```

QEMU:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda buildroot/buildroot 2017.02.2/output/images/rootfs.ext2  -m 2G -smp 2 -nographic -kernel buildroot/buildroot-2017.02.2/output/images/bzImage -append "console=ttyS0 root=/dev/sda debug earlyprintk=serial slub_debug=QUZ"
```

i don't understand why i am unable to see message "Welcome to buildroot" ??

Comment: Have you set your console device properly in */etc/inittab* inside the image? I just run **qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -m 256 -net nic -kernel vmlinuz-andy -initrd initrd-andy -append "console=tty1 console=ttyS2,115200n8 ignore_loglevel" -no-reboot -nographic -serial null -serial null -serial mon:stdio** and everything works for me.

Comment: Thanks, please explain about `-initrd initrd-andy` ?

Comment: I'm using *initrd* instead of real rootfs image.

Comment: Yes i use it, again i have problem to see "Welcome to buildroot"!!

please look to screenshot :
http://s8.picofile.com/file/8297197384/Screenshot_from_2017_06_08_18_05_05.png

Answer (score 1):

If you use QEMU nographic option, please check following bullet points:

- `BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_PORT="ttyS0"` in buildroot config file
- `console=ttyS0` in kernel args when run QEMU

Comment: So if I get it right, he saw plenty of boot log because ttyS0 was the default boot console, but it wasn't a login console, and the system instead tried to wait for a login on an nonexistent (?) graphical display. Right ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to modify the bootloader parameter..set the console to ttyS?
or you can modify the rootfs.tar, in the rootfs, edit the `etc/inittab`
for instance,change ttymxc1 to ttymxc0:

```
# Put a getty on the serial port
ttymxc0::respawn:/sbin/getty -L  ttymxc0 0 vt100 # GENERIC_SERIAL
```

Answer (score -1):

Take the sdcard.img file in buildtoot>> output>> images>>sdcard.img
Then make it bootable using balena etcher(when using ubuntu) or rufus(when using windows).
Then flash to memory card.
Then put that card in fpga board.

It will surely work for everyone.
If any doubt: contact parthumahesh1998@gmail.com